# Why sprintf crash in this case?

Tags: c++, valgrind

I'm running the following function:

```
void f () {
    int n = 10;
    char *buffer = new char[n*2];

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

        sprintf(buffer + (i*2), "%.2X",i);
    }

    delete[] buffer;
}
```

and in some cases this function crash.
Running valgrind, I can see the following problem:

```
==26747== Invalid write of size 1
==26747==    at 0x56CC2C9: vsprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==26747==    by 0x56AE456: sprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
```

Can anyone explain what's happening?

Comment: C-style strings have a terminating zero.

Comment: Did you intend to write `n` different strings? Or to concatenate the `n` sprinted strings into a single string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*buffer* is sized 20, but when *i* values 9 you do `sprintf(buffer + 18, "%.2X",i);` writting 3 characters because of the ending null character, and that null character is written at *buffer + 20* which is out of *buffer*

you need `char *buffer = new char[n*2 + 1];`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I run valgrind with the change, the problem disappears.

Comment: You welcome, you are right to use _valgrind_ this is a very great tool